# How do I format positive numbers with a + sign

Tags: google-sheets, format, spreadsheet

I'm trying to make an interactive D&D character sheet for my group to fit our homebrew ruleset but I've never really worked with this before.

I'd like to make it so the modifiers from the base stats are displayed with a + or - depending on its value. It's already adding the - properly but I can't figure out how to add the + in front of the number if it's 0 or higher.

Currently using the format `=((B5-10)/2)`
with B5 being the base stat where 10 is average and should be '+0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the number format. The same way you can format a date as `dd/mm/yyyy` you can set formats for numbers. First, select the rows, columns or cells you wish to affect, then use the Format menu to apply a custom number format: `+#,##0;-#,##0`.

The format before the semi colon is applied to positive numbers, the format after is applied to negative numbers.

The comma is optional depending on how you want to format it. If you want to have decimals just add `.00` after the zeros. Change the decimal zeros to a pound sign if you don't want to truncate the number.
The zeros represent 'must-have' place holders. The pound symbols represent optional place holders.
E.g. `0,000` would show the number ten as **0,010** as opposed to `#,##0` which would display as **10**